# Server library API to send request to server from Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, api

I want to write application for facebook and vkontakte, which will consist of such main blocks as: SocialNetworkAPI (which include all work dedicated to social networks: posting to wall, get all user's info) and ServerAPI (which will send HTTP POST requests to my Java based server and receive data from there in JSON).

I am looking now to 
[Adobe flash URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfe.html)

So, my question is: is there any good ServerAPI libraries, which I can use or rework to prevent rewriting standart code lines. What can you propose me? Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to ServerAPI -> as to an loader library then you can use:
http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

and then use

> src.com.adobe.serialization.json

library classes to convert responce to object.

Comment: the LoaderMax is more a normal Loader on speed (meaning: it's for loading assets, not data to/from the server) than an URLLoader.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook you can use the Adobe API:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

The situation with vkontakte isn't such good. I've found only this:
http://code.google.com/p/vkapi/

Actually universal server libraries just cannot exist as every game (not social) server is unique.
About loading tools: if you use Flex in your app, there is RemoteObject class representing a remote service:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/mxml/RemoteObject.html